# Type error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignparentleft' in package

Tags: android, xml

Hi I keep getting this error and have not found a solution.I have changed Api level and then did the same thing for the build target.I have no idea what is wrong here.Please could you help.

> ```
>         android:minSdkVersion="14"
>        android:targetSdkVersion="18"
> ```

list_item.xml file

```
<relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <textview
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignparentleft="true"
        android:layout_alignparenttop="true"
        android:layout_marginleft="26dp"
        android:layout_margintop="23dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textappearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
    </textview>

</relativelayout>
```

this is main xml file

```
<relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <listview
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignparentleft="true"
        android:layout_alignparenttop="true" >
    </listview>

</relativelayout>
```

I am getting these errors

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignparenttop' in package 'android'
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignparenttop' in package 'android'
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_margintop' in package 'android'   
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignparentleft' in package 'android'
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textappearance' in package 'android' list_item.xml
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_alignparentleft' in package 'android' list_item.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just typo `<relativelayout>` in your `XML`. It should be `<RelativeLayout>`

Take a look at [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

also correct `textview` to `TextView` and `listview` to `ListView` @Aldo Borrero's comment

Comment: Also correct `textview` to `TextView` and `listview` to `ListView`.